# Make text boxes different sizes

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have some fields (such as name, phone number, company) a user can fill out. The text boxes are good sizes, except for one, which is a "note" field. I want the note text box to be very large when compared to the other text box fields, but I am only able to make all the text boxes the same size.

_form.html.erb/vendors

```
<%= form_for @vendor do |f| %>

#this text field will be a regular size
  <p>
    <%= f.label :company %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :company %>
  </p>

#more code...

#I want this text field to be large
 <body>
     <div class = "notes">
         <p>
             <%= f.label :notes %><br>
             <%= f.text_field :notes %>
        </p>
     </div>
 </body>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

</div>  

<% end %>
```

my css file

```
input[type=text]{
    width: 40%;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: white;
}


textarea {
    width: 20%;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: white;
    resize: none
}

#more code...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class with the style (width) you want for that `input`:

```
.large-box {
  width: 60% !important;
}
```

Then, add it to your `input`:

```
<%= f.text_field :notes, class: "large-box" %>
```

Comment: @bockdavidson Maybe its being overwritten, try using `!important`. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cols and rows property. `<%= f.text_area :notes, :cols => "10", :rows => "10" %>`
 You can also just specify size like: `<%= f.text_area :notes, size: "60x12" %>`